# Сохранение логов IIS в базу данных

Tags: windows, iis

Как задать сохранение логов в базу данных? Должен же быть формат ODBC, но я не могу его нигде найти.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODBC Logging - опциональная фича. Его нужно поставить в Add / Remove Windows Features (в дестктопе) или через Add Role Services (на сервере):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только на живом сервере [его лучше не включать](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/odbclogging):

> The major disadvantage to using ODBC logging is the performance for logging because when ODBC logging is enabled, IIS disables the kernel-mode cache. For this reason, implementing ODBC logging can degrade overall server performance.